# Javascript and html, UI construction

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

First of all, thats [what i need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUkpp.png)

So i started to get a value for a;
its like `Please check code 1;
code 1: https://jsfiddle.net/o4pqzcug/`;

Then i add dropdown menu for change functions than, all messed up :)

`There is a upgraded one:);
code 2:  https://jsfiddle.net/uaucawwe/1/`

How can i use dropdown with myfunction() and implement altercanvas function.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got this, if you want to check;

```
 Here is the latest version;      https://jsfiddle.net/uaucawwe/4/`
```

I just deleted function named altercanvas and make one function :)